# Windows 10 automatically enters Quiet Hours

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1709

#### Background

Since some months already Windows 10 starts the quiet hours mode over and over again automatically. I mostly recognize it when using Telegram and no notifications are arriving.

I then check the notification center icon and in most cases there is **no** icon, which indicates the quiet hours mode being active. In other cases sometimes the indicator is showing up. I always need to disable it manually after it happens.

---

#### Question

Is there any way to check what activates the quiet hours (something like logging accesses to the registry key), or maybe even a way to completely disable quiet hours forever?

---

#### Additional info

```
Edition:    Windows 10 Pro
Version:    1709
Build:      16299.125
```

I also use the automatic night mode for reduced blue light, if that matters.

Comment: Have you checked Event Viewer? It may give some hints on what happens.

Comment: @Zalatik I will definetly check next time it happens. I will let you know the result.

Comment: There was nothing in the Event Viewer. I am currently checking the key(s) via Process Monitor. It logs reads/writes to the values. I see that Avast is doing quite some delete/write activity on that key.

If I find more, I'll add it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disabled hibernation by command powercfg -h off

Disable Fast Startup option in Control Panel.

Go to Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Security and Maintenance\Automatic Maintenance

UNCHECK "Allow scheduled maintenance to wake up my computer at the scheduled time". OK.

[image]

Restart.

Comment: Hmm, are you sure these steps are related to the 'Quiet hours' settings? That's the mode where you don't receive notifications from any app.

I'll try them anyway. Thanks.